# How to display a numeric keyboard in objective c ipad sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ipad

How do I display a numeric keyboard/pad on the iphone or ipad?

How can I display it in a popoverview only and not the standard way (at the bottom of the device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose the type of keyboard that is shown, check out the [UITextInputTraits Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits). Changing the keyboardType property will give you a numeric keyboard (set it to UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad).

I don't believe there is any built-in way to display the keyboard in a different location; you would have to create your own custom view that has the input keys / buttons that you need.

Comment: Note that there is no UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad on the iPad at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is last active 1 year ago, but this might help somebody out there.

You can try implementing this one https://github.com/azu/NumericKeypad. The coder implemented his own number pad buy subclassing the UITextField.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see how it implemented:

https://github.com/lnafziger/Numberpad

or

https://github.com/azu/NumericKeypad

Cheers!!!!!!!!